# É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?

Tags: c#, .net, using

É correto usar um bloco `using` dentro de outro bloco `using` como no exemplo abaixo? ou basta apenas colocar o primeiro `using`?

```
    public DataTable Listar(string stringMySql, CommandType commandType, List<MySqlParameter> lstParametros)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = StaticKey.RetornaStringConexao();
            mySqlConnection.Open();

            using (MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                mySqlCommand.Connection = mySqlConnection;
                mySqlCommand.CommandType = commandType;
                mySqlCommand.CommandText = stringMySql.Trim();

                if (lstParametros != null)
                {
                    mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(lstParametros.ToArray());
                }

                using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    using (MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand))
                    {
                        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                        return dataTable;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Está absolutamente correto. Cada recurso precisa de seu próprio `using` para garantir o encerramento dele quando não mais for necessário. Pode melhorar um pouco aqui:

```
using (DataTable dataTable = new DataTable())
using (MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)) {
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

É possível usar um bloco só com mais de um recursos aberto. Ao final do bloco, ambos serão encerrados.

Na verdade tem um problema aí. O código está retornando algo que está sendo disposto. Isto não vai dar certo. Se vai retornar o recurso para fora do método, você não pode dispor dele. Neste caso o `using` não deve ser usado para que o recurso permaneça vivo. Assim:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
using (MySqlDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)) {
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

Ou em alguns casos (não nesse):

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
try {
    using (var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)) {
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
} finally {
    if (dataTable != null) dataTable.Dispose();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/UsingDouble.cs).

Mas é necessário que quem chamar este seu método faça a liberação do recurso manualmente ou usar um padrão do `using`. Este é o tip ode código que vejo muita gente errar e depois não entender porque acontece problema mesmo usando o `using`.

Um detalhe interessante é que agora (C# 8) não precisa mais criar blocos para o `using`, só declarar a variável sem o bloco e o escopo passa ser o bloco atual. Só isto:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
using var mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand));
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
return dataTable;
```

Em C# 8 já pode usar `using var` assim não precisa criar um bloco só para o `using`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, programar de certa forma é fácil o difícil para mim muitas vezes é ter a certeza se o que estou fazendo esta sendo feito da forma correta e limpa e nesse caso sua resposta deixou bem esclarecido para não errar mais.

Comment: Pra isto estamos aqui.

Comment: @Maniero, resposta esclarecedora e objetiva. Muito bom.