# Existe quantidade máxima de utilização do "using"?

Tags: c#, using

Minha duvida inicial era, se estava certo utilizar `using` dentro de `using`, consegui saná-la nesta resposta:

[É correto usar um bloco using dentro de outro bloco using?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101535/)

Porem fiquei me perguntando, existe quantidade máxima?

Ou seja, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
 private void clickMovimentoEstoque()
    {
        GridView viewMat = null;

        TextBox codigo = null;
        TextBox qntBaixa = null;
        TextBox lote = null;

        if (xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage == xtraTabPage2)
        {
            //componentes
            viewMat = gridView2;

            codigo = textBox9;
            qntBaixa = textBox7;
            lote = textBox4;
        }
        else if (xtraTabControl1.SelectedTabPage == xtraTabPage5)
        {
            //mp
            viewMat = gridView10;

            codigo = textBox14;
            qntBaixa = textBox13;
            lote = textBox12;
        }

        using (viewMat)
        {
            using (codigo)
            {
                using (qntBaixa)
                {
                    using (lote)
                    {
                        qntBaixa.ForeColor = Color.Black;

                        //para garantir que a quantidade informada nunca vai ser maior que a quantidade pendente para baixa.
                        decimal qnt = 0, qntInformada = 0;
                        decimal.TryParse(viewMat.GetRowCellValue(viewMat.FocusedRowHandle, "QNT").ToString(), out qnt);
                        decimal.TryParse(qntBaixa.Text, out qntInformada);

                        int tipoMaterial = 0;
                        int.TryParse(viewMat.GetRowCellValue(viewMat.FocusedRowHandle, "tipoMaterial").ToString(), out tipoMaterial);

                        string un = viewMat.GetRowCellValue(viewMat.FocusedRowHandle, "UN").ToString();

                        //talvez iremos precisar comparar a unidade, pois no modelo atual, se for materia prima (tipomaterial = 0) pode dar baixa em quantidade maior que a planejada
                        //mas temos como mp mpbr, entre outros que tem sua unidade de medida como pç, nao podendo dar baixa maior que o solicidado            

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qntBaixa.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lote.Text) && qntInformada <= qnt && tipoMaterial != 0 ||
                            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qntBaixa.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lote.Text) && tipoMaterial == 0)
                        {
                            confirmaMovimento();
                        }
                        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qntBaixa.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lote.Text) && qntInformada <= qnt)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um lote, para continuar!", "Movimentos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(qntBaixa.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lote.Text) && qntInformada <= qnt)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um item, para continuar!", "Movimentos", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        }
                        else if (qntInformada > qnt)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Quantidade informada é maior que a quantidade pendente para baixa!", "Movimento", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }                
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não há nada especificado, pode usar quanto quiser, você esbarrará antes em outras limitações, que já são bem altas e ninguém bate nelas. E se bater fez a coisa mais errada da história da programação :)

Este código, por exemplo, salvo estar absurdamente ofuscado, precisa de zero `using`s.  Todos os objetos que foram usados, além de estar em forma incorreta não são descartáveis, portanto não funcionarão.

Comment: amigo, entendi obrigado pela resposta, poderia me dar uma breve ideia de como utilizar corretamente esses objetos? teria algum link? ou como posso procurar no Google?

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel, [Existe uma resposta aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66232/78713) que fala qual é a razão de se utilizar bloco using. Em resumo, é necessário quando uma classe usa recursos não gerenciados. O uso de recursos não gerenciados fazem com que o garbage collector, por exemplo, não saiba quando aquela instância do objeto 'morreu' a menos que seja chamado o método `Dispose` dele - sem isso ele ficará na memória eternamente. O que o bloco using faz é: ao final da execução daquele bloco chamar o método `Dispose` do objeto implicitamente (você não vê, mas ele faz!).

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel a maior parte do que você precisa saber está onde se fala de `Dispose()`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=dispose. Um bom *start*  seria aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173210/101. Obviamente  temos algumas *tags* que ajudarão hbem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dispose?sort=votes&pageSize=50 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/using?sort=votes&pageSize=50